# Unmarshalling an XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have some generated classes, which looks something like this:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Data", propOrder = {
    "body"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Data")
class Data {
    @XmlElement(name = "Body", required = true)
    protected Body body;
    // getter and setter
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Body", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
class Body {
    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement
    protected List<Object> content; 
    // getter
}
```

and some other classes for XML types:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Node1", propOrder = {
    "data",
})
class Node1 {
   @XmlElement(name = "Data")
   private String data;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Node2", propOrder = {
    "int",
})
class Node2 {
   @XmlElement(name = "Int")
   private Integer int;
}
```

An XML sample would be:

```xml
<Data>
    <Body>
        <Node1>
           <Data>abc</Data>
        </Node1>
        <Node2>
           <Int>abc</Int>
        </Node2>
    </Body>
</Data>
```

When I'm trying to unmarshall the XML, it returns a `JAXBElement<Data>`, and some of the elements from `Body.content` are of type `ElementNSimpl`, others are just Strings with a new line in it.

This is the way I'm unmarshalling the XML:

```java
private Object xmlToObject(String xmlString) throws Exception {
        var context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Data.class, Node1.class, Node2.class);
        var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        return unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlString));
    }
```

I expect to receive a `Data` object, which will contain the `Body` object, and the `Body` object will contain two elements, `Node1` and `Node2`, but the elements in `Body.conent` are, as I said, `ElementNSimpl`

Comment: May be it's getting confused by the duplicated Data element `/Data/Body/Node1/Data`. Try adding type to the last one `@XmlElement(name = "Data", type=String.class)`

Comment: Sorry, but no. these are just examples. Real classes have different names, there are no collisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you get JAXBElement when you unmarshal, indicates that your schema contains 2 or more global elements of the same complex type. See [this](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html) article for a  deeper explanation.

When I try your example, I do get a Data instance directly. No JAXBElement wrapper.

To get mapped class instances in a @Mixed  @XmlAnyElement list property, the mapped Java classes needs to be annotated with @XmlRootElement and the @XmlAnyElement must have its lax property set to true (see javadoc).

Comment: Thank you! It helped. I'm using ```JAXBIntrospector.getValue()``` to get the domain model instead of wrapper. And also, setting the lax property to true, helped to get the domain model instance instead of ```ElementNSimpl```. Still I have also some String elements in ```Body.content```, but I think I can iterate over them and get the item I need.